# Get Calendar busy/available status from the command line

Tags: macos, calendar

Can you access the MacOS Calendar busy/available status from the terminal? If not, is it possible to grab the calendar events of a local user?

I know this can be done with GraphQL, but I am hoping for a local option. (I am using MacOS, but i'd be interested in a windows option as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
find ~/Library/Calendars -name "*.ics" |
      xargs grep -h -e "SUMMARY" -e "DTSTART" -e "DTEND"
```